# Differences betwen findById and load?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

What's the main difference between `FindById(id,callBack)` and `Load(id,callback)` ?

More details:

I'm new to MEAN stack web development, so i'm just playing with Mean.io:

This code is generated by Mean.io(controllers/article.js):

```
Article.load(id, function(err, article) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!article) return next(new Error('Failed to load article ' + id));
    req.article = article;
    next();
  });
```

Just i wanted to do the same result using findById it' well documented at: [Model.findById](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)

```
 Article.findById(id, function (err, article){
  if (err) return next(err);
    if (!article) return next(new Error('Failed to load article ' + id));
    req.article = article;
    next();
});
```

It works, but i wanted to know the main differences between them, strange that i can't find any doc on mongoose docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` is a static method for the Article model that does exactly the same thing as the `findOne` and is [**defined in the schema**](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/articles/server/models/article.js) as follows:

```
ArticleSchema.statics = {
  load: function (id, cb) {
    this.findOne({ _id : id }).populate('user').exec(cb);
  }
};
```

whereby the [`findById`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L1078) method also calls the `findOne` method:

```
Model.findById = function findById (id, fields, options, callback) {
  return this.findOne({ _id: id }, fields, options, callback);
};
```

Comment: Thank you i can confirm your answer: http://www.100percentjs.com/handling-data-in-mean-io-with-mongoose-js-and-angular/